# Upon scaling, fix the size for specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I view my site on my phone, I can prevent it from resizing/scaling with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

However, I want to be able to resize, but is it possibly to keep some of the elements fixed scale?

Basically, if I have

```
<header>stuff</header>
<div id="content">
    Content
</div>
```

When I zoom in on my phone, "content" would zoom in as normally, but the header would remain fixed size. The font for header would be the same size, look the same, etc.

There is too much text for me to consider using images as an alternative option.

Basically, I'd like to have a `user-scalable=no` kinda thing for specific elements.

JS/jQuery approaches are all ok, and yes, I know that one of the solutions is to go about resizing everything manually, or making everything a percentage, but that's ugly and not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I just read your last sentence, but I don't think that my solutions look ugly, do they? ;) Honestly: It's about how the GUI looks like, not the code, and HTML is far less ugly than any procedural language including JS...so I'm not sure about the motivation of your question. However, in programming the things must be done one way or another, if we like it or not.

Comment: Of course percentages are a perfectly valid approach, but when I have layouts so complicated that I have hundreds of elements, it really isn't preferable. It's the simplest solution to my knowledge, but this question was to see if there was a simpler one.

Comment: I'm not to keen to suggest this as an answer, but have you tried... [*iframes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)? They are part of HTML5 spec, after all, and you should be able to apply different `viewport` properties to separate documents - think "container" html with two iframes for "stuff" and "content".

Comment: @o.v. that's great! I mean its pretty clunky but it's simple and solves my problem. Thanks!! If you'd post it as an answer I'd be happy to reward the bounty.

Comment: @Overcode: [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20341325/1081234). You might want to try making this work with the "stuff" header moved into the container html... because two iframes on a page is just one too many :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iframes is *pretty clunky but solves your problem* :) They are part of HTML5 spec, after all.

You should be able to apply different viewport properties to separate documents - think html with *stuff* header and *content* iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>stuff that you want to be "fixed"</header>
    <!-- #content document will have different viewport meta applied
         it should also be sized appropriately -->
    <iframe id="content" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems to be a more appealing option than my original suggestion of having both the header and the content set up as separate iframes inside of container html.

Comment: Sweeeet. And yep as per your previous comment, two iframes is one too many. Really I just need one part to stay fixed scale. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, two iframes is *two* too many :) I'm glad this helped.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If I remember correctly,pages in iframes cannot be scaled separately.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unless you use a custom "scalable area," you cannot keep only certain elements to their original size.

By *custom scalable area* I mean what libraries like [iScroll 5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5-ready-for-beta-test) create. This allows the user to [pinch-to-zoom only specific parts of the page, (open on mobile)](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/zoom/)  rather than the whole page like mobile browsers normally do.

By using something like iScroll, you can what you want to be zoomable inside its *scalable area* and the rest outside of it: that way it will not be scaled.

Either that or, well, what Trendy suggested: manually fix all elements after the scale.

Comment: I liked o.v.'s suggestion more, but that library is pretty interesting. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is easy because **most percentage values are relative to the viewport** so it can be done with normal HTML/CSS.

You just need to define for every object some relative values of width and height in CSS, something like `width:30%; height:30%;`

But you can't place the object with absolute values, because otherwise they're moving. So you also need percentages like `left:30%; top:10%;`, without forgetting to set the `position:relative`

Even more, the marging and padding (and maybe even the border ;) of all the container-divs - even the body - also needs to be relative or zero, otherwise the object would move, too...

Here's a working code example with an image (you could also just define another div with percentual sizes instead of the img):

```
<body style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px">
    <div style="margin:5%; border:0px; padding:5%">
        <img src="my picture.jpg" style="width:30%; height:30%; position:relative; left:30%; top:10%;">
    <div>
</body>
```

(Note that the percentages of the picture are always relative to the viewport and have nothing to do with the picture size)

**UPDATE:**

I just made some fancy coloumns:

```
<div style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:2%; width:30%; position:absolute; top:10%; left:5%;">
    <div style="margin:0px; border:3px double #000000; padding:2%; width:90%;">aaa
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:2%; width:30%; position:absolute; top:10%; left:35%;">
    <div style="margin:0px; border:3px double #000000; padding:2%; width:90%;">bbb
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:2%; width:30%; position:absolute; top:10%; left:65%;">
    <div style="margin:0px; border:3px double #000000; padding:2%; width:90%;">ccc
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case the height depends on the content. In a productive environment you should also remove the borders, because they're zooming.

If you also want to have constantly sized text, you need to use some javascript function since those new CSS3-relative fonts don't really work well.

**UPDATE 2:**

Now I know what you mean: You want to work with absolute values due to the size control of the elements itself.

So you need to calculate the needed relative values on the server, and sent them to the client. However this only works with JS, because you need to get browser resolution information from the browser and send them in an XMLHttpRequest to the server. Then you probably use innerHTML to build the header, it's the best way to do it (the "Facebook way"). And because you use relative values, all your problems are solved...and the graphics are even much faster than any (other) JS solution.

However, you also need a solution for deactivated Javascript on static loading...and then it will still zoom in/out, it's unpreventable. But if there is another way to get the browser viewport than by JS please let me know. ;)

**P.S.** *Since I was getting many downvotes for this post, any comments from the downvoters are most appreciated, thx.*

Comment: I know that this is a valid approach, and it's also the simplest solution I can think of, but I was asking for a simpler solution. It might not exist, but this still isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, my solution is indeed quite simple. It's much more simpler than doing it in pure JS (think of all the debugging and cross-browser issues). You just need to learn how to do a XMLHttpRequest and load the returned string via innerHTML (this is only "almost AJAX" because pure AJAX is only with XML, nowadays being replaced by JSON...but you don't even need those data formats, you can just get pure HTML and update the page with innerHTML).

Comment: This solution isn't simple when I have hundreds of divs. But that aside, like I said, it works, and I know it does, but I was just asking to see if there was anything simpler.

Comment: When you say it works, did you try to implement it? Because I'm trying to implement it now, and it's not that simple as you may imagine...in fact it's a quite complex thing to do (about 100 lines of code or more, especially the fonts redrawing is tricky). That said: Probably you are better off with an existing framework like jQuery.

Comment: And again I must repeat myself: It doesn't matter how much divs you have. If you aline them by hand, it's the same work using absolute or relative values. And if you aline them by a server side script (something like "newLeftPosition = oldLeftPosition + widthOfElementLeft" and "newTopPosition = oldTopPosition + heightOfElementAbove") it's very easily done.

Comment: no I meant it's annoying because I'd have to convert every single div I have from px positioning to % positioning. You're really misunderstanding me, what you gave me would totally solve my problem, but my question wasn't looking for just any solution, it was looking for a simpler solution than the ones I have.

Comment: @Marcus: Would you clarify what you mean by (and provide source) for "any percentage values are relative to the viewport"? That's quite a bold statement (hehe), especially since you recommend setting margins/paddings/borders as relative values while [border widths cannot take a percentage value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties) and [margin/padding percentage values are based on the containing block's width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties).

Comment: @o.v: In my examples I set border:0px which is correct...and if the block size is a percentage value, the margin/padding will also become relative to the viewport. Have a look in my code examples. Cheers

Answer (score -3):

Since there is no reliable way to achieve what you are asking in all browsers, I'll assume you're targeting mobile Webkit browsers.

First you'll need [the detect-zoom package](http://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/).

Next you'll need to use the device pixel ratio to resize the element you want to stay at a fixed size:

```
(function(){

    var el = document.getElementById('yourDiv'),
        ratio = detectZoom.device(),
        theWidth = el.offsetWidth,
        theHeight = el.offsetHeight;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        if(ratio >= 1.0){
            theWidth = Math.round( theWidth/ratio );
            theHeight = Math.round( theHeight/ratio );

        }else{
            theWidth = Math.round( theWidth * ratio );
            theHeight = Math.round( theHeight * ratio);

        }

        ratio = detectZoom.device();
        el.style.height = theHeight + "px";
        el.style.width = theWidth + "px";

    });

})(window);
```

Comment: That's not what I meant at all. I wanted it so that if you scaled, NOT resized, the page, the div would remain the same size. Basically, if you hit Ctrl + or zoomed in on your phone, it would still look the same.

Comment: Updated, hopefully that helps.

Comment: this only resizes the div, but the elements inside the div like text will still resize.

Comment: Without the actual source code I cannot provide the entire answer. I assumed you would be able to see what is happen and apply the solution to fit your needs. I.E. You need to make this work with all the child elements as well. http://jsfiddle.net/5nhe4/  <---That should give you an idea of what happens. You will also need to resize the text for the elements as well as the elements themselves.

Comment: yes but I specified that manually resizing everything wasn't what I was looking for